# JavaScript math calculation case

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to do a JavaScript calculation which goes something like this:

1-500,000 points $30/100,000 points

500,001-999,999 points $25/100,000 points

1,000,000+ points $20/100,000 points

I have case switch which will check the value and then get the correct sum but I want to know how I can do for example if user enter 4,500,000 points or some random value which is more then 1,100,000.

This is what I have currently:

```
  if (Number(amountOfPoints) > Number(0)) {
    switch (true) {
        case (amountOfPoints > 0 && amountOfPoints <= 100000):
            {
                price = 30;
                break;
            }
        case (amountOfPoints > 100000 && amountOfPoints <= 200000):
            {
                price = 60;
                break;
            }
        case (amountOfPoints > 200000 && amountOfPoints <= 300000):
            {
                price = 90;
                break;
            }
        case (amountOfPoints > 300000 && amountOfPoints <= 400000):
            {
                price = 120;
                break;
            }
        case (amountOfPoints > 400000 && amountOfPoints < 500000):
            {
                price = 150;
                break;
            }
        case (amountOfPoints > 500000 && amountOfPoints < 600000):
            {
                price = 150;
                break;
            }
        case (amountOfPoints > 600000 && amountOfPoints < 700000):
            {
                price = 160;
                break;
            }
        case (amountOfPoints > 700000 && amountOfPoints < 800000):
            {
                price = 185;
                break;
            }
        case (amountOfPoints > 800000 && amountOfPoints < 900000):
            {
                price = 210;
                break;
            }
        case (amountOfPoints > 900000 && amountOfPoints < 1000000):
            {
                price = 235;
                break;
            }
        case (amountOfPoints <= 1000000):
            {
                tweetsPrice = 200;
                break;
            }
        default:
            price = 0;
            break;
    }
}
```

How can I calculate if points is > 1,100,000? It should increment by $20 for each 100,000.

### Update

Perhaps it was not clear what I need. Here is what I need: once the value is over 1,100,000 the price to be calculated accordingly, for example for points between 1,100,001 and 1,200,000 price will be $220, for points between 1,200,001 and 1,300,000 will be $240, etc, without limit, so for example for 4,500,001 and 4,600,000 price will be $720.

Comment: Why the jQuery tag? I see none.

Comment: @j08691 It's there in spirit

Comment: Seems like an if statement is in order, and you don't need to do both "sides" of the comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, it works like this:

```
function calcPrice(value) {
  if (value <= 500000) {
    return 30 * Math.ceil(value / 100000);
  } else if (value <= 1000000) {
    return 150 + 25 * Math.ceil((value - 500000) / 100000);
  } else {
    return 275 + 20 * Math.ceil((value - 1000000) / 100000);
  }
}
```

but going by the letter of your post:

```
function calcPrice(value) {
  if (value <= 500000) {
    return 30 * Math.ceil(value / 100000);
  } else if (value <= 1000000) {
    return 25 * Math.ceil(value / 100000);
  } else {
    return 20 * Math.ceil(value / 100000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/csrow/KMGsc/1/) You can type in the points and see the rewards value.

Your point system seems arbitrary so I changed to always start on 1 rather than sometime 0 and sometimes 1.  If you don't like it, then you can change the function.

```
function points(inText) {
    var inNum = (isNaN(Number(inText))) ? 0 : Math.floor(Number(inText));
    inNum = Math.floor(inNum / 100000);
    if (inNum < 5) {
        inNum = inNum * 30;
    } else {
        if (inNum < 10) {
            inNum = (inNum - 5) * 25 + 150;
        } else {
            inNum = (inNum - 10) * 20 + 275;
        }
    }  
    return inNum;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm a little tired but I think this might work for any amountOfPoints:

```
var price = 30,
    strPoints = amountOfPoints.toString(),
    points = Number(amountOfPoints);

if (points >= 100000) {
  var multiplier = Number(points.toString().substring(0, 5 - strPoints.length));
  price += 20 * multiplier;
}
```

Basically just doing `price = 30 + 20 * the_significant_digits_of_amountOfPoints` where amountOfPoints is greater than 100,000. The substring part gives you 1 when there's 6 digits, 2 when there's 7, and so on.

This should work for the use case "It should increment by $20 for each 100,000". But your case statements assign values to price that don't follow this pattern. So you'd have to use this code after your points are large enough to surpass the conditions in those.